# Set the data file to use in Jekyll dynamically

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a partial that loops over data a file, and I have a few different files with the same schema. I want to use the same partial for each data file and set a variable with the data file name.

So, I'd want to change this:

```
<ul>
  {% for item in site.data.testFile %}
    <li>{{ item.nm }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

...to something like this:

```
<ul>
  {% assign data_file = testFile %}
  {% for item in site.data.data_file %}
    <li>{{ item.nm }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do that? I can't find anything in the docs that explains making this kind of thing dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almos there, surround the test file name with quotes and access the data array directly with `site.data[data_file]`:

```
<ul>
  {% assign data_file = "testFile" %}
  {% for item in site.data[data_file] %}
    <li>{{ item.nm }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one not works for me. I have the `testFile` part in a subfolder: `site.data.references.subfolder`

```
<ul>
  {% for item in site.data.references[subfolder] %}
    <li>{{ item.nm }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```